# Dismount and re-mount a component on each button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to conditionally render a custom notification component (not 100% sure how it works, it was written by others and it uses material-ui). I want this notification to appear every time a button gets clicked, but for some reason the notification component will stop re-appearing after it auto-hides itself after some time, even when I click the re-click the button - again, I'm not totally sure how this works.

I just want to know if there's a way to dismount and then re-mount this custom notification component so that it gets newly rendered on each button click (is that bad practice?). This is a simplified ver. of my current logic:

```
const RandComponent = ()=>{
const [notifType, setNotifType] = useState(1);

const toggleNotif = ()=>{
   setNotifType(!notifType);
}

const getNotif = ()=>{
     return <Notification type={notifType}/>
}

return (<>
   ....
   <button onClick={toggleNotif}>TOGGLE</button>
   {getNotif(notifType)}
</>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
const RandComponent = () => {
const [showNotification,setShowNotification] = useState(true):

const toggleNotificationHandler = () => {
     setShowNotification(p => !p);
}

return (<>
   <button onClick={toggleNotificationHandler}>TOGGLE</button>
   {showNotification && <Notification />}
</>)
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to toggle whether the notification appears or not, but rather the type of notification (e.g. notifType === false makes an error popup render while notifType === true makes a success popup render)